# Configurable Product Options not visible on frontend

Tags: configurable-product, magento-2.2.1

I have created a configurable product with color (Red and Blue) and size (5, 6, 7 and 8) as two options.
I can see all the associated products in admin correctly. But on frontend I am getting only color option to select and there is nothing to select under size option on frontend.  
All the child simple products are enabled and are in stock. 
I have performed the indexation and flushed all the caches but no luck. 
It will be very helpful if anyone can guide me to figure out the issue here and how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to max input variable setting on the server. 
I have increased the value of `max_input_vars` and the issue is resolved.